# how to capture the details of a face?

Tags: post-processing, lighting, portrait

I have been browsing in behance and i fell in love with his work.
how do you do this kind of photography?
its so clean and detailed, if this is edited in PS then can you post some links fo any tutz?

https://www.behance.net/Fresh-art

Comment: Can you link a specific picture that you link?

Comment: Do you have a camera you'd like to try to replicate it with as close as possible, or are you looking for whatever it takes to get that look (ie new equipment) ?

Comment: Definitely see [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6765/what-goes-into-making-smooth-crisp-fashion-magazine-worthy-shots?rq=1) and @MattGrum 's answer .   If its not a duplicate of that question, its very very close.

Comment: Actually, Matt's answer would be a near-complete miss. Please take the time to look at what actually goes into commercial retouching; it may be only a part of the process, but it is *at least* as significant a part of the process as the photography itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best techinque to smooth skin?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/what-is-the-best-techinque-to-smooth-skin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost all of those images have seen significant retouching using so-called "high end" techniques, particularly **frequency separation**, **dodging and burning**, **colour grading** and **high-pass sharpening**. There are a huge number of tutorials on YouTube for each of those techniques (with varying degrees of quality, both of the tutorials themselves and the retouching skill of the poster). Some of the better ones are by [Jonas Wendorf](http://www.youtube.com/user/jonaswtuts), [Michael Woloszynowicz](http://www.youtube.com/user/vibrantshot) and, if you can find them (speaking Spanish helps a lot) Natalia Taffarel. You will find many additional tuts in the "related videos" sidebar. (Please note: Woloszynowicz's work has slipped into the "obviously retouched" category lately. His dodge and burn work to reshape faces is quite artificial-looking, but the techniques he uses are still very valid. You just need to know how far to go.) (Many of the images seem to have been taken from the ModelMayhem "Challenges, Contests and Samples" retouching thread, where you can find all sorts of raw images to practice on.)

Still, all of the images started with a shot that was very good. Lighting and control of focus/depth of field are critical starting points, otherwise you're left with the task of creating what is really just a painting based on a photographic reference.

Comment: While I think post is certainly part of it - I think the majority comes from the lighting.

Comment: Not really, @rfusca. The details in question are things like the texture of the skin (particularly the "sparkle" in the highlights), and even if you trowel the makeup on, using something that's heavily mineralized (mica-like plates), and blast the lighting in, you can't come close without significant post. The out-of-camera image, while critical to the overall success, is just the starting point; you can't build on a bad foundation, and even in the best photographs of the most perfect models, you can't get textural extremes without magnifying flaws.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase then.  I mean, while you certainly have to do significant post to get there - I don't think any amount of post would make it like that without the way the lighting is done.

Comment: The point of the answer is that no matter how much effort you put into "getting it right in camera" (which would include all of the "pre" work, like makeup and styling), you can't get images like those without significant post-processing work. And no, Lightroom and/or adjustment layers, masked or otherwise, will not do it.

Comment: I was studying frequency sep and dodging and burning and colour grading/HP sharpening is new to me. thank you so much!